# Detect KPsensor HoneyPot

Tags: honeypot

Is there any pattern or characteristics to identify a kpsensor? It is one of the most used.

I have noticed that of the number of supposedly open ports, only those with a real service running respond to the `nmap -sV`, the others can give the same services (but the response time is equal to the other false ports) or not respond

Comment: Are you sure it's KPSensor and not KFsensor?

Comment: Sorry some later , but I was say KFsensor,, is mine error.